# How to loop through an array of objects and compare it with table data values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, html-table

My HTML table

```
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Average</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="tableBody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Sample table generation

```
var arrayofObjects = [{sID: 025, name: John Doe, average: 80}, {sID: 893, name: Jane Smith, average: 82}];

    function loadTable() {
                let table = document.getElementById("tableBody");
                table.innerHTML = "";
                let tr = "";
                vararrayofObjects.forEach(x => {
                    tr += '<tr>';
                    tr += '<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" id="sIDNum">' + x.sID + '</a></td>' + '<td>' + x.name + '</td>' + '<td>' + x.average + '</td>';
                    tr += '</tr>'
                })
                table.innerHTML += tr;
            }
```

What I tried to get value of first column (sID) on click then loop through object array

```
const tableBody = document.querySelector('#tableBody');
        tableBody.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            vararrayofObjects.forEach((element) => {
                if(element.sID == $('a').text()) {
                    var personName = element.name;
                    var personID = $('#sIDNum').text();
                    var personAvg = "Average " + element.average;
                }
            });
        });
```

Problem is that the if statement returns me all values of `$('a').text())` instead of the one I clicked on. How do I properly implement it so that clicking on my anchor tag on the first column (`sIDNum`) will get its value, then use that value to loop through my object array and get the values of the object that matches with it?

Comment: `$('a').text()` - if you saw/ran this out of context, what would you think it would do?

Comment: IDs must be unique, `id="sIDNum"` is applied to all of them, `$("#id")` gets the first.

Comment: @freedomn-m from what I know, it'd return the value of the anchor tag that I clicked on since it's inside the event listener.

Comment: Ah, fair answer.  No, `$("'a")` returns *all* the `<a>` elements across the whole document.   Within an event handler, `e.currentTarget` will be the element you clicked, while `e.target` will be `tableBody` as that's where the event is attached.  So `$(e.target).find("a")` will give you all the `<a>` for the entire tbody.   So you need `$(e.currentTarget).closest("tr").find("a")` to get the `a` for the current row.